# Problem retracting custom fields

Tags: content-type, column, custom-field-types

I have this project with custom field for a content type.

When I deploy the first time after creating the new field everything is fine. Once i retract the solution my field is the only one left on the site, it wont retract. When i publish after that i get this error

> "The field with Id {1ef18d86-3fe6-4c8c-b22a-377c2e98c17d} defined in
>   feature {03118f5c-a57b-40f8-b908-c9c8d3174f01} was found in the
>   current site collection or in a subsite"

And a warning saying pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens in Visual Studio when using VS to deploy (and redeploy) declarative content types to a SharePoint site. I’ve seen it happen most often when deploying List Definitions and List Instances. There are a variety of steps out there to try to make it go away:

1. Retract solution, close VS, restart VS, deploy solution.
2. Deploy project, attempt to activate via UI, deactivate, retract, restart VS, deploy solution.
3. Deploy, retract, deploy. Open Task Manager, kill VSSHostP4.

Deploying after this should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you've retracted it and it appears to still be there, can you actually click on it without getting any errors ?

Try running an iisreset /noforce after you've retracted it and before you deploy it again.

Also double check your schema.xml and elements.xml to make sure the GUIDs all match up with the field and the content type.

Ian.

Comment: Yes i can delete it without any error and browse it. My guids are also fine unless they cant have capital letters and i do not have schema.xml in the project only the feature that deploys element.xml which has the field declarations and the content type that uses them. (using vs2010 guid generator)  If the iis thing works will i be obligated to do this everytime i deploy ?

Comment: Iis reset doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have braces {} around your GUIDs ?